# How to write multiple citation in one bracket cite package?

Tags: cite-package, multiple-citations

I am using "cite" package to cite multiple package into single bracket. But, it is not working. For example.

```
\usepackage{cite}

Previous studies~\cite{sinha,saha,Meli2019HowBC} have extracted secrets from the GitHub repositories, but none made their dataset public for future research purposes.
```

The output is like below:

[image]

I want the citation to merge as **[2,9,10]**. Am I missing any options?

Comment: Please tell us how you load the `cite` package. E.g., do you load it with any particular options? Please also tell us which bibliography style you employ.

Comment: I have used only this to load the package. \usepackage{cite}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should not happen. There must be something wrong you're doing while loading the `cite` package. Or you could be loading some other conflicting package at the same time.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cite}

\begin{document}
Previous studies~\cite{sinha,saha,Meli2019HowBC} have extracted
secrets from the GitHub repositories, but none made their dataset
public for future research purposes.

\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\bibitem{sinha}
The sinha reference.
\bibitem{saha}
The saha reference.
\bibitem{Meli2019HowBC}
The Meli2019HowBC reference.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

The above source produces:

[image: result 1]

And if you add more references in between (as in your example, I presume):

[image: result 2]

---

**Update:** The `IEEEtran` package (that OP used together with `cite`) explicitly wants citations to be formatted in separate brackets and overrides the behaviour of `cite`. According to [its documentation](https://mirror.dogado.de/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/IEEEtran_HOWTO.pdf):

> Citations are made with the \cite command as usual.
> IEEEtran will produce citation numbers that are individually
> bracketed in IEEE style. ("[1], [5]" as opposed to the more
> common "[1, 5]" form.) The base IEEEtran does not sort or
> produce compressed “ranges” when there are three or more
> adjacent citation numbers. However, IEEEtran pre-defines
> some format control macros to facilitate easy use with Donald
> Arseneau’s cite.sty package [16]. So, all an author has to do
> is to call cite.sty:
>
> `\usepackage{cite}`
>
> and the adjacent citation numbers will automatically be sorted
> and compressed (ranged) IEEE style. (Of course, multiple
> adjacent citations should always all be declared within a
> single \cite, comma separated, for this to work.)

So, when the two packages are loaded as in the following source:

```
\documentclass[10pt,conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[noadjust]{cite}
\begin{document}
Previous studies~\cite{sinha,saha,Meli2019HowBC} have extracted secrets from the GitHub repositories, but none made their dataset public for future research purposes.
\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\bibitem{sinha}
The sinha reference.
\bibitem{saha}
The saha reference.
\bibitem{Meli2019HowBC}
The Meli2019HowBC reference.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

the result is this:

[image: result 3]

If the range does not have consecutive numbers, as `[2], [9], [10]` in your case, no compression occurs. This is how it is intended to work. I understand it's not what you want, but it's what `IEEEtran` wants.

Comment: These are my packages.

\documentclass[10pt,conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multicol, multirow, tabularx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{algorithm, algpseudocode}
\usepackage{url}

Comment: I updated my answer.